# Snowflake insert into table column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I insert into a table array column without using a select:

```
insert into demo.array_table 
  select array_construct(array_construct('cars','motorcycles','trucks','vans'),1);
```

I can't seem to use `VALUES()`.

Comment: You could use `array_agg` instead, which would then create an array from a table of records, which could be created using `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SELECT for Array column.

More details in Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#examples

A couple of examples are listed in the article: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-an-INSERT-statement-to-add-an-ARRAY-column-to-the-table